# Drywall “box” around firewall penetration inside stud cavity

Tags: electrical, drywall, fire

In my condo (three floor building) the interior walls are all Fireguard-grade 5/8 drywall attached to 11 gauge structural steel studs (which SUCK except for when hurricanes blow through). Each original penetration has a fireguard “box” around it. I’m wondering if this is necessary? The construction is party wall, so there are four sheets of Fireguard between my interior and my neighbors. I’m told my interior wall is required to be 1hr firewall.

[image: picture of drywall box inside stud cavity]

Comment: Never seen that before.  But then again my experience has all been with single family dwellings.  Why don't you ask your local building/inspection department?  Even if something like that is not required by code (but I don't know if that's the case or not), your jurisdiction may have stricter standards,

Comment: Are there any penetrations to the other side of the wall in the adjacent stud spaces or above the junction box?

Comment: @nosparksplease - there are not. There is a double firewall between my place and the neighbor’s interior firewall.

Comment: What is penetrating the firewall at this location? a few PEX water pipes?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - only a 1G receptacle box. No penetration through back firewall. The blue conduit you see is smurf tube, supplying the 120v THHN.

Comment: @benmarks -- ENT was the other thing I would have guessed, didn't notice the receptacle box until now though.  How many smurf tubes penetrate the firewall? Just one coming out the back of that receptacle box?

Comment: In this case there are three penetrations of that odd “box”. But literally anywhere there is any box penetrating my interior wall, it’s boxed within the stud cavity. If the studs were solid I could maybe understand, but they are slotted every 2’ to facilitate pass through of cables/conduit.

Comment: @benmarks -- I see where the "box" is penetrated, but that's not the question at hand: I'm asking how many things actually cross the boundary of the firewall itself

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - 4 gang spread across a ~30’ wall.

Comment: @benmarks -- I mean, *at this point in the wall*

Comment: Just the one gang outlet. Nothing behind. Nothing in the same stud cavity. I’m stumped.